# PHP Contact form not working with bootstrap html

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm fairly new to web development and PHP and i've been having trouble trying to get my contact form to work with the Bootstrap template

I am getting an error:

Error 405(Method Not Allowed):

> send  @   jquery.min.js:2  ajax   @   jquery.min.js:2
>   (anonymous)   @   contact.js:18  dispatch @   jquery.min.js:2
>   y.handle  @   jquery.min.js:2

contact.php

```
<?php


$from = "@example.com";
$sendTo = "@example.com";
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'subject' => 'Subject', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

index.html

```
        <div class="main-form">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- contact form -->
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                         <form class="form" id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact.php" role="form">
                            <div class="messages"></div>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="form_subject" type="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea id="form_message" name="message" placeholder="Message *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Message."></textarea>
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send message">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you for any help

javascript

```
$(window).on("load",function (){

    $(".loading").fadeOut(500);

     // contact form
    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you show the javascript code for the ajax call?

Comment: Added the javascript, I've also added a <section id="contact-form" class="contact section-padding" style="background: #fafafa;"></section> tag to encompass the form but it's still not working.

Comment: how are you mounting that server? Apache? Nginx? just php -S? I just replicated it in JQuery 3.2 and I had no issues with my post (with a php -S).